# Is it correct to use "straight through" in the following sentence

Tags: phrases, expressions

I want to say that I watched a video from the beginning to the end without stop. In this case, can I say "I watch it straight through" ?

I googled the meaning of "straight through" and came across this article (Do you read books straight through?
https://blog.nathanbransford.com/2011/10/do-you-read-books-straight-through) where "straight through" is used as "in order" or "page by page". It seems to me that "straight through" doesn't have the meaning of "nonstop" which I want to emphasize in the previous example.

Thanks.

Comment: *straight through* is fine for your context. Alternatives include *I want to watch it **in one/a single session/sitting***, or ***...without interruption***, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Straight through* does indeed mean “in one sitting with as few interruptions as possible,” as a [Stargate fan explains](https://forum.gateworld.net/archive/index.php/t-427.html):

> We're currently rewatching the entire series on DVD and DVR during the hiatus. We're averaging about 2-3 eps a night. We usually watch a movie, so 2-3hrs isn't unusual. The most we've ever watched straight through is 5, I think...probably when I was home sick from work. By "straight through" I meant not counting pauses to answer the phone, get food, take the dogs out, etc.

You are also correct, however, that *straight through* can also mean “from beginning to end, in order, from cover to cover,” which only makes sense with anthologies or other compilations like the [Bible](http://www.marcalanschelske.com/reading-bible-genres/) which are not generally read in such fashion.

In some cases, both [meanings seem to be in play](http://several-instruments.blogspot.de/2017/08/bingeing-tchaikovsky.html):

> I can't remember all the times I've been warned by a reviewer not to listen to an album all the way through in one sitting, but I'm going to go ahead and do the opposite. I've enjoyed this seven-disc set of Tchaikovsky orchestral music immensely in the last couple of weeks, and I found that listening straight through from the First Symphony to the Serenade for Strings gave me a new appreciation of Tchaikovsky's art, which hasn't always resonated with me in the past.

This reviewer of a seven-disc set of Tchaivosky's works speaks of numerous listening sessions, but the overall plan is to take them in order, though not necessarily at one sitting, a practice the reviewer sees as analogous to his enjoyment of the recordings. He does seem to suggest, however, that listening to all seven recordings in one sitting would be an ideal way to listen to them.

Answer (score 2):

I think saying that you "watched the video straight through" does indeed communicate from beginning to end in one viewing session. In my experience this is common usage. The word straight indicates the sequential aspect you mentioned in the question. The word through implies to the very end and all together. To be very clear in your meaning, you could extend the statement thusly: I watched the video straight through from beginning to end.

Answer (score 1):

"I watched the video in one go" means I watched it without stopping.